# Html5 video source with base64

Tags: base64, html5-video

I am trying to play html5 video encoded with base64 but its not working. It works without encoding. What is the problem?

```js
var s = 'http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4';
var video = document.createElement('video');
document.body.appendChild(video);
video.src = "data:video/mp4;base64," + btoa(s);//not working
//video.src = s;//works
video.autoplay = true;
video.controls = true;
```

Comment: Your base64 data is just the string `"http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4"`. Definitely not binary data of an mp4 file. Why don't you pass the url directly, without going through a dataURI.

Comment: Because I wanted to procect the source somewhat.

Comment: Forget about that. The ones that want it will find it.

Comment: Certainly there is no method against video downloaders even using php if not javascript alone?

Comment: Well youtube isn't able to protect themselves from this. And even if there are technologies like DRM which make it harder, no there is no really bullet proof solution.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var s = 'http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4';
fetch(s).then((res) => res.blob()).then((blob) => {
  const fileReader = new FileReader()
  fileReader.readAsDataURL(blob)
  fileReader.onload = () => {
    const videoEl = document.createElement('video')
    videoEl.src = fileReader.result
    videoEl.controls = true
    document.body.appendChild(videoEl)
  }
})
```

You can do this, but it's not recommended. You should use an objectURL instead of a dataURL.

Comment: Where is base 64 in your code? Also, your code throws an error for fetch().

Comment: @Garric `fileReader.readAsDataURL` returns base64 encoded string.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function displayVideo (base64){
  var video = document.getElementById("video");
  var binaryString = atob(base64String);
  var blob = new Blob([binaryString], {type: "video/mp4"}); // Replace "video/mp4" with the type MIME of your video
  video.srcObject = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
}
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Comment: Where is base 64 in your code?

Answer (score 0):

```
 let reader;
    reader = new FileReader();
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      reader.readAsDataURL(files);
      reader.onload = (data) => {
        resolve(data.target.result);
      };
    });
```

Comment: What does this add to kaijun's 2021 answer?